# What is the error in my Result.Scan()?

Tags: go, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to learn Go and am trying to scan rows into values which I will then assign to a struct. It seems like not all values are making it into the struct but I don't know why. Below is the full script. Running the query against the server actually returns results. However, when I test in the Scanned results, no data appears. 
In this case, the expected results would be 
"en"
"en"
Below is the script. I'm pretty sure I'm messing something up with my struct or with my types (or both).

```
package main
import (
    "log"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"  
)
//local variables
var cnstr = "cnstr"
var dbdriver = "postgres"
//data structure
type WordData struct {
    Word string
    WordID int  
    Root string
    RootID int
    PartOfSpeech string
    Case *string
    Person *string
    Gender *string
    Number *string
    Tense *string
    Voice *string
    Mood *string    
    Transliteration *string
    Root_Definition *string
}

func main() {
    db, _ := sql.Open(dbdriver, cnstr)
    var word string
            var wordid int
            var root string
            var rootid int
            var partofspeech string
            var caseval *string
            var person *string
            var gender *string
            var number *string
            var tense *string
            var voice *string
            var mood *string            
            var transliteration *string         
            var definition *string  
    if db != nil {
        err := db.QueryRow(`select 
                                    morph as word, 
                                    morph_id as wordid, 
                                    lemma as root, 
                                    lemma_id as rootid,
                                    part_of_speech as partofspeech,
                                    "case",
                                    person, gender, number, tense, voice, mood,                                     
                                    transliteration,                                                                        
                                    definition
                                 from texts where sort_order = 65006`).Scan(&word,&wordid,&root,&rootid,&partofspeech,&caseval,&person,&gender,&number,&tense,&voice,&mood,&transliteration,&definition)

        switch {
        case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
                log.Printf("No user with that ID.")
        case err != nil:
                log.Fatal(err)
        default:
                /*wd := new (WordData)
                wd.Word = word
                wd.WordID = wordid
                wd.Root = root
                wd.RootID = rootid
                wd.PartOfSpeech = partofspeech
                wd.Case = caseval
                wd.Person = person
                wd.Gender = gender
                wd.Number = number
                wd.Tense = tense
                wd.Voice = voice
                wd.Mood = mood              
                wd.Transliteration = transliteration            
                wd.Root_Definition = definition  */             
                wd := WordData{
                        word,
                        wordid,
                        root,
                        rootid,
                        partofspeech,
                        caseval,
                        person,
                        gender,
                        number,
                        tense,
                        voice,
                        mood,                       
                        transliteration,                        
                        definition}             
                fmt.Printf("Printf: %s",wd.Transliteration)
                fmt.Println(transliteration)    
        }


            //or, comment out and use the other initializer type


    }
    db.Close()
}
```

Comment: What is the error value of `results.Scan()`?

Comment: @topskip there is no error

Comment: I'm suspicious of your use of `*string` as the type of `Transliteration` etc.  Just try `string` or if you want a nullable string use `sql.NullString`.

Comment: @nick thanks. I've tried with just string and got the "driver" error (nil->string) and thought that *string was the same as sql.NullString. I'll give that a try. Thanks

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood in the end the sql.NullString was the correct approach, but I can't figure out how to encode it using the native json encoder so I changed the query to COALESCE NULL values.

Comment: @swasheck have a look at https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/encode.go#L41-L82 for the type conversions. Also, thanks for the reminder about COALESCE! I'd forgotten that function, and it's *very* useful.